# stepinfo command in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am comparing two controllers PID implemented in simulink in ode45 and Fuzzy PID implemented in ode14x. The parameters obtained from stepinfo command are:

```
For PID:
 RiseTime: 163.4001
 SettlingTime: 875.1394
 SettlingMin: 327.8981
 SettlingMax: 414.6694
 Overshoot: 13.7639
 Undershoot: 1.7550
 Peak: 414.6694
 PeakTime: 384


For Fuzzy PID:
RiseTime: 0.8010
SettlingTime: 1.9812
SettlingMin: 364.0289
SettlingMax: 364.5573
Overshoot: 0.0157
Undershoot: 1.7550
Peak: 364.5573
PeakTime: 3
```

Firstly what are the units of parameters as mentioned above. Secondly what could be the reason of huge difference between parameters of the two controllers. Any guidance..

Comment: The time units are probably the same time units as your signal, no?

Comment: No..Just take the example of settling time for PID its value is 875. In simulation its the 875 iterations after which it converges same is true with settling time of fuzzy PID.